# Возвращать количество вызовов метода в любом экземпляре класса

Tags: java

Имеется класс Class, который имеет публичный метод int h(), который возвращает количество вызовов метода h в любом экземпляре (включая происходящий вызов, т.е. первый вызов метода h в данном экземпляре класс вернет 1).

Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Как то так (thread-safe вариант)

```
public class MyClass {
   static AtomicInteger count=new AtomicInteger(0);

   public int h() {
      return count.addAndGet(1);
   }
}
```

Не thread-safe вариант:

```
public class MyClass {
   static int count=0;

   public int h() {
      return ++count;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Фактически в дополнение к ответу Barmaley 
Если вы объявите в классе переменную с модификатором `static`, то она будет одинаковой для всех экземпляров данного класса. В такой переменно вы можете хранить любые общие для класса данные, а сама переменная не будет привязана к конкретному экземпляру класса. В многопоточном исполнении поток может создать свою локальную копию переменной, поэтому в этом случае нужно позаботиться чтобы переменная была потокобезопасной (thread-safe).